# proof $[f(b)-f(a)]g'(c) = [g(b)-g(a)]f'(c)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous functions and differentiable in $(a,b)$ , show that $\exists c \in (a,b)$ such $[f(b)-f(a)]g'(c) = [g(b)-g(a)]f'(c)$

I tried using the mean value theorem, but I can not relate the two functions with the same c.

any help is appreciated

Comment: Thanks for the links. I did not know this version. Should i delete this topic ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the *Cauchy Mean Value Theorem*.

Hint: Work with

$$F(x) = \left[ f(b) - f(a) \right] g(x) - \left[g(b) - g(a) \right] f(x) $$

on the interval $(a, b)$. Evaluate $F(a)$ and $F(b)$. After expanding fully, what do you notice? An application of Rolle's theorem will complete the proof.

Comment: I am not that familiar with the custom practice here on MSE, but I pointed out a possible duplicate which has an answer with a quite similar proof. So why not just flag/vote to close as a duplicate?

Comment: I looked at the link and the answer given did not provide a proof ... it only gave an example and the intuition behind the theorem.

Comment: Did you have a look at the second answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/296187/42969 ?

Comment: No I did not. I see it now. I'll leave this answer here unless the OP indicates that I should remove it. I also approached it in a different manner using Rolle's Theorem instead of IVT (yes I know they are similar).