# Cauchy Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am trying to finish the proof started in the first comment of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114694/proving-cauchys-generalized-mean-value-theorem).
I have that $$h'(x)=g'(x)[f(b)-f(a)]-f'(x)[g(b)-g(a)]$$ then $$h'(c)=g'(c)[f(b)-f(a)]-f'(c)[g(b)-g(a)]=0$$ by Rolle's theorem. Then
$$g'(x)[f(b)-f(a)]=f'(x)[g(b)-g(a)]$$
But then I am stuck...
Do I just simply show by algebra that $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$$ and I am done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $g'(c)[f(b)-f(a)]-f'(c)[g(b)-g(a)]=0$ we get

$g'(c)[f(b)-f(a)]=f'(c)[g(b)-g(a)]$

It follows that

$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$

(if you have the equation $xy=uv$ then $x/u=v/y$ provided that $u \ne 0 \ne y$

Comment: Thank you for the help. :)