# Is this a bad proof for Cauchy mean value theorem or is it valid?

Tags: calculus, analysis

By MVT, $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$$
$$\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}=g'(c)$$
so, $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)} = \frac{\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
}{\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$$

I think it is not a valid proof but I am having a discussion with a classmate and I am not sure anymore...

Comment: It is not valid. What you can say is $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$ and $\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}=g'(d).$ But you have to prove that $c=d.$

Comment: That is what I was thinking as well. Thank you!

Comment: To convince your classmate consider $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^3$ on $[0,1].$ Note that $c=1/2\ne d=1/\sqrt{3}.$

Comment: Just linking this so it is easeir to find, took me some time .https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114694/proving-cauchys-generalized-mean-value-theorem?noredirect=1&lq=1